# Printing to terminal when redirecting stdout

Tags: python, unix

I have a little command line script  that prints its results to the stdout which I then usually redirect to a file. A part of the script is needs to ask the user for some input via the terminal, but the input prompt of course is redirected to the file as well, so that the user does not know what to do:

*eggs.py*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("foo")
    choice = input("Eggs and Spam? ")
    print("bar")
```

How can I make it that the input-promt will be directed to the terminal, regardless of where the stdout is directed, so that:

```
python eggs.py > test.txt
> Eggs and Spam?
```

and *test.txt*:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: A much better design is to get rid of interactive I/O and let the user specify any parameters or inputs as command-line arguments or from an input file.

Comment: Well, sometimes you need the user to interact with your stuff during runtime. In this case I need the user to decided if a datapoint should stay in the dataset or if it shall be ignored. That cannot be decided apriori.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps not exactly meant for displaying things to the terminal, but using stderr will do what you want:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("foo")
    print("Eggs and spam?", file=sys.stderr)
    choice = input()
    print("bar")
```

Comment: That was my first idea as well, but as soon as the stderr is also redirected to a logfile this becomes problematic again

Comment: If you can cooperate with the caller, they can open additional file descriptors before running your script. Or you can wantonly write to `/dev/tty` and hope it's defined. (There are ways to check, but no good way to fall back when it's not a terminal.)